# How to check which process generated click event

Tags: c#

I got a problem which I tried to solve by writing program in c# but it doesn't seem to have info I need. Some time ago something started generating clicks in my windows every x seconds, I am wondering if there are methods of checking which process generated such an event so I can deal with it. I basically checked MouseEventArgs in C# but didn't find anything useful there.

Also in another way:
I am developing a game, I want to make protection against bots. Is there any way to check where did event that was passed to game came from? If it was generated by hardware mouse or by some process? And if it was generated by some process is there a way to know which process generated such event (like key press, mouse click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the most info you will get is to Hook the keyboard using the low level hook (See [`LowLevelKeyboardProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) you won't have the process that generated the keystroke but in  `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT.flags` you will have the `LLKHF_INJECTED` bit set and you will know that it was injected.

To know if it was targeted to your app [`GetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will give you that.

For your "Game" case you will also need to check if it doesn't require elevation as it will be annoying for your users.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to set a breakpoint in the routine being called and look in the call stack which process started the event. If you're in luck it's one of your own routines. If you're unlucky it's a routine of an external source.